# Adjusting subreport headers in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, bids

I'm trying to create a sort of master subreport that I can use as a header for other reports.
The subreport has 2 image logos in the left and right corner. I insterted the images in the body of the subreport.
My struggle here is to make it as universal that it works with all reports.
Some of the destination reports even though they are all A4 size reports, have different size report bodies. For example, the destination report is a bit more narrow than the subreport with header,  in the preview I end up with a wider header than destination report body, the header clearly takes the width from the header subreport. Is there a setting or a way that I could set the width of the subreport header to fit to the destination report width?

The only possible workaround currently I can think of is to play with the margins etc in each of the destination reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to handle this: Use an internal parameter that defaults to false to toggle the visibility of elements like title blocks and images.

When including the report as a subreport, set that parameter to true and you'll have a stripped down data-element only version.  Then put titles and other formatted layout around the subreport in your master report.  That way you can make everything line up there.